# Generate k most subsets unique pair of elements

Tags: python, math, parallel-processing, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am writing a Cuda application that should calculate a function over two elements of my set S. But the order of the pair doesnt make any difference, so: `f(a,b)` = `f(b,a)`

For that reason, I want to generate all subsets of S with max size K, without duplicating pairs of elements between the sets.

In other words, given any two subsets, I don't want the intersection of them to be larger than one element. (This way I can avoid calculating the function of those two elements multiple times)

Example:

Given `S={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and `K=3`, the output should be something like this:

```
{ {1,2,3}, {1,4,5}, {1,6,7}, {1,8,9}, {2,4,6}, {2,5,7}, {2,8}, {2,7,9}, {3,4,7},
  {3,5,8}, {3,6,9}, {4,5,9} }
```

But the output should not look like this:

```
{ {1,2,3}, {1,4,5}, {1,6,7}, {1,8,9}, {2,4,6}, {2,5,7}, {2,6,8}, {2,7,9}, {3,4,7},
  {3,5,8}, {3,6,9}, {4,5,9} }
```

Because the intersection of `{2,4,6}` and `{2,6,8}` is `{2,6}`.

Comment: Could you please take some time in writing your question? It should contain a [short, self-contained, correct, example](http://sscce.org/); a clear description of what the problem is and a description of [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I think you might have accidentally omitted some parts of your question.

Comment: This isn't really well defined because simply creating all subsets of size K as `{1,2,3}` `{4,5,6}` etc will satisfy your critera

Comment: This is possibly an interesting question, I don't really see why it had to be closed.  Repost after you work out what you're looking for a little more concretely.

Comment: Don't repost; edit the question. There's already a vote to reopen it.

Comment: Keep editing. Problems: 1) You talk about "pairs" but your example involves triplets (but with one pair). Which one do you want? Both? Singletons too? 2) Your examples don't contain all possible combinations, only some of them. Do you want all possible combinations? Only some? How are we to decide which ones? 3) What do you mean by "I prefer something binary"?

Comment: I removed the binary part, i think that was making more confusion than helping out.

Comment: What is your goal? Maximizing the number of subsets? Minimizing? Don't care either way?

Comment: Minimize the number of intersections between the subsets is kind of my goal

Comment: @user1363214, thanks, I think I understand more. Look at my edits and see if they reflect your intent. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Right, but that's trivial, just generate all subsets of size k from 1..k, k+1..k+3 etc. If you want to maximize the number of sets with no overlap, that's a differnet question

Comment: @spinning_plate, its not, in your solution, the output should be:
{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}
I wouldnt calculate f(2,5), for example

Comment: a function over elements 2 and 5.

Comment: Meaning you need 2 and 5 to be in the same set?  So there is some list of constraints taht these sets need to satisfy?

Comment: @spinning_plate, `f(2,5) = f(5,2)`; it's not really relevant, only as an indication that the order of elements doesn't matter. The OP is looking for the maximum number of subsets of size `K` of the set `S` where no more than one element of `S[x]` exists in `S[y]`, `S[x]` and `S[y]` being arbitrary subsets of `S`.

Comment: no. i just need that 2 and 5 appear together in any of these subsets.
Its like a combinatorial problem, but with less subsets. Because, for example, {1,2,3} and {1,2,4} are kind of redundant subsets, because i would do the same f(1,2) twice

Comment: @Ben - this is what I thought, but I'm not sure the OP is saying he wants the maximum # of subsets

Comment: @user1363214 are you trying to generate the C(N, K) subsets of S?

Comment: @spinning_plate, "I want to generate all..."; I assume it's the maximal number of subsets.

Comment: @Boud, something like this. But i would like to filter the combinatory output in order to the subsets with intersection of more than one element would be cut off my result. For example: C(N,K) would give me {1,2,4}, {1,2,3}, but the intersection between them give me {1,2}, i dont want this.

Comment: Then I think you get a non-commutative issue in your predicates ; to get your example from your original question, what is the rule you want to apply to make a difference between {2,4,6} and {2,6,8}: you expect {2,4,6}, {2,8}, but why don't you expect {2,4}, {2,6,8} ? ...

Comment: @Boud, 4 and 6 would never be a pair in a subset.

Comment: I made a program to test this and i got this output: `(1, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 6, 7)
(1, 8, 9)
(2, 4, 6)
(2, 5, 7)
(3, 4, 7)
(3, 5, 6)
(2, 8)
(2, 9)
(3, 8)
(3, 9)
(4, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 8)
(5, 9)
(6, 8)
(6, 9)
(7, 8)
(7, 9)` Is that valid? If not could you please explain why?

Comment: Also in your example `{1,4,5}` and `{4,5,9}` have the same pair `{4,5}`

Comment: @user1363214 I don't get your answer: what math total order function do you apply to remove any {x, 4, 6} that would have made {2, 8} the only left choice. Edit your post and provide your math equations if they are clear for you, it will remove the hide and seek game

Comment: @jamylak could be that =) could you send me how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, chain
>>> s = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
>>> k = 3
>>> seen = set()
>>> subset_sizes = reversed(range(2,k+1)) # [3,2] for this example. Reversed since you favor the sets with larger values of K
>>> for item in chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,i) for i in subset_sizes):
        pairs = set(combinations(item,2))
        if not pairs.intersection(seen):
            seen.update(pairs)
            print(item)

        
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 6, 7)
(1, 8, 9)
(2, 4, 6)
(2, 5, 7)
(3, 4, 7)
(3, 5, 6)
(2, 8)
(2, 9)
(3, 8)
(3, 9)
(4, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 8)
(5, 9)
(6, 8)
(6, 9)
(7, 8)
(7, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a non-answer in hopes it helps us nail down the question: The question I'm answering below is

> Given a set S, generate the maximal cardinality set of all subsets of
>   S such that each subset is less than size K and no two subsets contain 
>   an intersection of cardinality > 1

If we fix the size of the subsets (k=3 rather than k<=3) you want, this is easy to do in an non-efficient manner:

1. Generate all subsets of size k from S
2. Keep removing things until no intersection is present

Some questions come from this

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this
2. Does **not** fixing k change this solution, is it optimal to always take subsets of a largest size
3. Is there an optimal set such that we can choose a size t<=k and have all the subsets be of that size

For **2)** I think the answer is no:

Observation: For small N, simply generating the pairs is better than generating subsets of size K.   Generating a subset of size >2 eliminates only one pair, generating a subset of k eliminates k choose 2 pairs.  Choosing size K is only better if

```
n/(k choose 2) = k/(k!/(k-2)!2!) = 2n/(k*(k-1)) > (n*n-1)/2 = (n choose 2)
1/(k*(k-1)) > (n-1)/4n
```

Only for sufficiently large N is this true:

```
1/(k*(k-1)) > 1/4 
  (k*(k-1)) > 4, k>=3
```

For ***3)*** I think the answer is yes

The number of subsets is maximized at `C(n,k)/C(k,2)` , we can calculate this using the formula to find the optimal k.  If there are pairs that remain, we can simply add those to the list as if k=2

Comment: @user1363214 reposting here my last comment: I think you get a non-commutative issue in your predicates ; to get your example from your original question, what is the rule you want to apply to make a difference between {2,4,6} and {2,6,8}: you expect {2,4,6}, {2,8}, but why don't you expect {2,4}, {2,6,8} ? ...

Comment: I think we are losing time here: we just don't get from the OP his need for selection between 1,2,3 1,2,4 1,2,5 for S=1,2,3,4,5 and K=3. OP clearly lacks total order function that he doesn't provide.

Comment: @Boud - Agreed. I'm addressing the problem as if he doesn't care and he just wants the maximal set, which is still an interesting problem. If it turns out to be not related, I'll nuke my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
    P := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; setpartition(P, 3);
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, 

     {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, 

     {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}, 

     {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}}, 

     {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}}
```